# How to setup backbone.js to pass the model name when posting to the Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

Give a rails controller like GroupMembers, if you post to the update method, rails expects params as so:

```
[group_member][admin]
[group_member][user_id]
```

With backbone.js, when I set a collection in the view and then save, the collection posts without the [group_member] trailing the attributes, confusing rails.

Any idea how to handle this when using backbone + rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with rails > 3.1 you can easily accomplish this by setting

```
# in config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [:json]
end
```

so the incoming group_member send to the controller as {:admin => true, :user_id => 42} will be converted to {:group_member => {:admin => true, :user_id => 42}} see [rails_api](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) for more details.

Vice versa it works with (see rails_api):

```
# in config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  self.include_root_in_json = false
end
```